# Would it be on-topic to ask on Literature what was the name of, URL of, or what happened to, that Philip Larkin online forum last seen about 2005?

Tags: discussion, scope

Would it be on-topic to ask on Literature what was the name of, the URL of,or what happened to that Philip Larkin online forum that seems to have disappeared from the internet? I saw it in about the year 2000 plus or minus less than five years, I think. People were posting questions about what a particular Larkin poem meant, and it was very busy. At the time I saw it, if someone replied to your post, or added to its thread, it would be displayed at the top of the menu, and then gradually sink down off page one and eventually off it into relative obscurity until the next reply.

Any information at all would be much appreciated. Does anyone else even remember seeing this site?

Comment: There's some [informal discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59798280#59798280) about this question